# Oracle 11g dbms_java.start_jmx_agent throws an exception

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, jmx

I'm trying to profile a Java stored proc inside an Oracle DB. My user has been granted role `JMXSERVER`, but when I run `call dbms_java.start_jmx_agent('22222', 'false', 'false');` I get:

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Management agent class failed 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JAVA", line 803
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JAVA", line 812
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I've traced the error to this line in JDK: https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/management/Agent.java#L483, and the exception details are printed to `System.err`, but where does Oracle write its stderr to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redirect the output like this:

```
select DBMS_JAVA.SET_OUTPUT_TO_SQL('1', 'begin dbms_output.put_line(:1); end;','TEXT') from dual;
```

Then the error will be printed to the SQL session output. In my case the culprit was a missing file `javavm//lib/management/management.properties`, so I went to server admins.

Answer (score 1):

You can also redirect the Java System.out and System.err to DBMS_OUTPUT:

```
dbms_java.set_output(100);
```

By the way, I tried the DBMS_JAVA.SET_OUTPUT_TO_SQL function as provided by Alexey but it failed with "Parameter 2 has invalid SQL" error. Did it work for you?